# Is it possible to change look of ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

Is it possible to change the look of unity interface of Ubuntu to make it look like KDE in fedora?
Thank you.

Comment: Why not just install kubuntu-desktop or kubuntu?

Comment: What exactly do you want to change? Your question seems very broad. If you want KDE, why don't you use Kubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

Of course, it's entirely possible. This [`article`](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/kde) can help you.

- Go to to the Ubuntu Software Center, search for *`kubuntu-desktop`* and then install *`Kubuntu Plasma Desktop`*.

  [image]

---

To install via command line, you can use:

```
$ sudo apt-get install kde-plasma-desktop
```

This package installs KDE desktop with minimal applications, and you can continue to use you ubuntu/gnome apps with it. Just select KDE from the login menu once it has been installed (see image below).

[image]

<sub>Image taken from psychocats.net</sub>

The KDE packages will be automatically updated through update manager once installed.

See more info(https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingKDE).

Comment: Psycocats is bloody brilliant - however, it would *really* help to have the necessary details (install kubuntu desktop) and the pitfalls (mixed packages between DEs) in your answer.